# Any recommendation to prevent rims sticking to the disc?

Tags: winter, wheels

Almost every season when changing the tires from winter to all-season and back I find the rims stick (mostly due to rust) to the disc behind.

Is there any recommended solution that can be applied between the rim and disc to prevent that? Rims are regular steel ones, the car is Civic.

Answer (score 5):

Some vehicles seem to be more problematic than others. I have had some luck by cleaning the rim and the hub with a wire brush spun by a drill. You want to clean the rust or corrosion off. Apply a liberal coating of anti-seize compound to the center hole of the rim. In areas where road salt is used in the winter, the use of wheel covers or hub caps may provide some additional protection.

Comment: One thing I would add: make sure not to apply any anti-seize to the threads of the lug studs (or the lug bolts, if the car is so designed). Torque specs for wheel mounting is typically specified with no anti-seize lubricant, and adding anti-seize to the threads can cause overtorquing of the lugnuts.